# Using Microsoft Z3 in a Silverlight app?

Tags: silverlight, z3

Has anyone managed to get a Silverlight 4 app to use Microsoft Z3?

It doesn't seem to work, I think because it seems to use native windows dll's.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Z3 DLL is native code and that is most likely the source of your problem. I understand that the upcoming version of Silverlight or, as Eric suggested, the beta, support this.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for whether it's written in native code or not, but if it is, you have two options:

1. Wait for Silverlight 5 (or use the beta today)
2. Create a web service that uses Z3, then use silverlight as a layer in front of it, shipping parameters and answers back and forth.

Hope that helps!